# Is mqtt is better than http

Tags: http, mqtt

MQTT is lightweight protocol. In IOT MQTT is most popular. With MQTT can we use REST APIs?

If yes, then why do we use HTTP instead, we can use MQTT as it is lightweight also battery consumption in case of mobile devices.

Comment: Man I don't know why there's a lot of dislike, it's a genuine question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the biggest differences is that HTTP follows a request/response model, whereas MQTT follows a Publish/Subscribe model. HTTP typically uses short-lived connections to make these requests, whereas MQTT typically keeps a TCP connection open for a long period of time.

See here for another question about MQTT battery/power usage:
[MQTT connection consumes less power](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362582/mqtt-connection-consumes-less-power/37365570#37365570)